# How can I find all files with a certain line in the source?

Tags: linux, debian

I am using linux trying to find all files that contain the phrase "Hello" in them (not the filename) and then delete them all. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
grep --recursive --files-with-matches Hello $HOME | xargs -d '\n' rm -f
```

Of course you need to be sure that the grep is finding only the files you want to delete as this pipe is quite unforgiving of errors

Comment: How can I remove the files that it finds?

Answer (score -2):

It took me 5 seconds to find google it:

find . -exec grep -n hello /dev/null {} \;

Of course, I could be lying and that could format your hard disk :^)

Comment: I don't know why my answer has been marked as not useful since it actually works... if its because of my sarcastic comment, I just wanted to point out that you shouldn't just execute arbitrary code that is posted.